# replacing list key name by variable in R

Tags: r

So let's say I want to create a list like that:

```r
x <- c(John=23, Mary=33)
```

Is there a way to substitute key names with variables. Something like that (but that doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```r
husband <- 'John'
wife <- 'Mary'
x <- c(husband=23, wife=33)
# Expected output: c(John=23, Mary=33)
```

In other words in the example above is there a way to replace `husband` with `John` etc.?

Comment: You can directly assign to a named vector by using double brackets: `x <- vector(); x[[husband]] <- 23`

Answer (score 2):

You may use `setNames`.

```
husband <- 'John'
wife <- 'Mary'
setNames(c(23, 33), c(husband, wife))

# John Mary 
#  23   33
```

Or with `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
unlist(lst(!!husband := 23, !!wife := 33))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! `unlist(lst(!!husband := 23, !!wife := 33))` - can you comment on `!!` and `:=` - what's going on here? or just point me to some docs

Comment: `!!` forces the evaluation of variable to it's corresponding data. Explanation is at `?\`nse-force\``

Answer (score 1):

In Base R:

A way that works for all names, and get's it from variable name:

```
names(x) <- Map(function(x) eval(parse(text=x)), names(x))
```

---

```
> x
John Mary 
  23   33 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `dput`

```
x <- c(John=23, Mary=33)
husband <- 'John'
wife <- 'Mary'

result <- dput(x)
```

output:

```
c(John = 23, Mary = 33)
```